# HELP NEEDED Block producer blocked by DigitalOcean - recover ADA?

Tags: stake-pool, ada

can someone please help me? I had just started setting up my stake pool, using DigitalOcean droplets to host the block producer & relay nodes. All was going really well. Then, for some crazy reason that has still not been explained to me, DigitalOcean blocked my account and refuses to give me access. So now I can no longer access the block producer. Fortunately, I copied all keys, certificates etc, payment address, but I cannot find how to recover the ADA that I had pledged to my stake pool. I would also like to know if anyone could also explain how to retire the stake pool after I recover my funds. Any help would be much appreciated and please, if you’re using DigitalOcean, please be careful they don’t do this to you. Thanks in advance, Simon

Comment: If you had copied your keys there will be no loss of funds. Please edit your question to include the methods followed by you to install the node and the keys you have in your possession. Do not give out the content of key files to anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have all your keys, you can start locally a node. When the node is synced, deregister your pool with **cardano-cli** by submitting a transaction with a **deregistration-certificate** created by the command **cardano-cli stake-pool deregistration-certificate [...]**

You don't have to recover the funds you pledged because you never lost control of your funds : you still have the signing key of the pledge owner address, do you ?

If you want to transfer your funds, you can create a wallet on Daedalus or Yoroi, and submit locally a payment transaction to transfer your pledged ADAs to this wallet. Be careful : **sign the transactions offline**.

Edited : gave more informations on the way to de-register a pool

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. When you mention the "signing key of the pledge owner address" you mean the payment.skey, is that correct? Thanks once again

Comment: yes, the payment.skey file

Comment: Hi, just to let you know, I followed your suggestions but actually spun up a new service using linode, copied all the files, synchronized, and now everything is up and running fine. Thanks again and thanks so much for your help, greatly appreciated